# Native error when running Java SQLite JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to run my Java program on a Raspberry Pi vA or vB. I'm using the SQLite JDBC library, which should support the Raspi. When I start the .jar, this error pops up:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0xac507cb0, pid=5789, tid=3057054816

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_65-b17) (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.65-b01 mixed mode linux-arm )
Problematic frame:
C [sqlite-3.8.11.2-38a14bad-15c4-42f0-8c15-a19159eabd43-libsqlitejdbc.so+0x5cb0]

Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

Stack: [0xb6320000,0xb6370000], sp=0xb636d6f0, free space=309k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C [sqlite-3.8.11.2-38a14bad-15c4-42f0-8c15-a19159eabd43-libsqlitejdbc.so+0x5cb0]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+0
j java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/io/File;)Z+328
j java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+48
j java.lang.Runtime.load0(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)V+57
j java.lang.System.load(Ljava/lang/String;)V+7
j org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadNativeLibrary(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+29
j org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.extractAndLoadLibraryFile(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+308
j org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary()V+224
j org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize()Z+0
j org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load()Z+19
j org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(II)V+355
j org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V+138
j org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V+4
j org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V+4
j org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V+4
j org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+24
j org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+2
j java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+171
j java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/sql/Connection;+13
```

The code works fine on Windows by the way.

I tried to find a solution and came across an issue that had some similarities: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/58 .
They seem to have found a solution, but the fixed library file is no longer available. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: The comment [here](https://github.com/gnosygnu/xowa/issues/27#issuecomment-210326328) contains a download link that appears to be obsolete, but you could try getting the tweaked SQLite JAR from a more recent XOWA release like [this one](https://github.com/gnosygnu/xowa/releases/download/v3.8.2.1/xowa_app_arm_v3.8.2.1.zip).

Comment: I just tried the jar from XOWA, gives the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone with the same problem in the future: the library fix used in eg. XOWA does **NOT** work on ARMv6, so Raspi A is not supported.

Here is a mirror of the patched library (3.8.11.2) if anyone needs it: https://mega.nz/#!RVlylBQL!w6ifnhXdtv6gqMtxLwEXBQjGJqQCsHIRnf1oZsafjdw .

Answer (score 1):

XOWA developer here. The Github thread has been updated with the latest answer, but I just wanted to reference it here, in case anyone stumbles across this post: https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/58#issuecomment-246115467

In short, the sqlite-jdbc jar in the XOWA arm package does work on Raspberry Pi. kwantuM may have still been using the old sqlite-jdbc jar

I excerpt more below. kwantuM or anyone else: please feel free to let me know if I should add / modify this comment.

Thanks.

---

````
I built a simple sample project to test yonisolos patch to get sqlite-jdbc working on Raspberry Pi.

Here were my steps to build the project:
* Used the sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar in at /xowa/bin/any/java/jdbc/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar 
* Built a Java project called piSqlite in Eclipse.
* Added sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar to the Build Path
* Wrote sample code to create and insert into a SQLite database. See the source code at the bottom of this comment.
* Compiled the Java project into a jar file
* Also, all three files are available here: https://mega.nz/#fm/q55wDRTR

Here were my steps to test the project:
* Copied the piSqlite.jar to my "Raspberry Pi 2 Model B 1GB" device
* Opened up Terminal and ran the following <code>java -jar piSqlite.jar</code>. I got the following output:
```
No connection string specified. Using default of 'jdbc:sqlite:test.db'
Successfully opened database: jdbc:sqlite:test.db
Successfully created table called 'test_table'
Successfully inserted record into 'test_table'
Successfully selected data; test_id=1; test_string=abcde
Successfully closed connection. Exiting...
```
````

Comment: This error is caused by ARMv6, see my comment. The GitHub solution is a solution for the UnsatisfiedLinkError which is solved by using the patched library.

Comment: Ok. I didn't realize that it did not work on Raspi A. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: This will still be useful for anyone getting the same error.